# What is the definition and action of Xcode scheme environment variable IDEPreferLogStreaming?

Tags: swift, xcode

What is the definition and action of Xcode scheme environment variable `IDEPreferLogStreaming`? What does `IDEPreferLogStreaming` enable or disable?

The warning shown below happen after changing `@UIApplicationMain` to `@main` per swift-evolution SE-0383 ["Deprecate @UIApplicationMain and @NSApplicationMain"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0383-deprecate-uiapplicationmain-and-nsapplicationmain.md)

```swift
// No IDEPreferLogStreaming warning
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {…}

// Causes IDEPreferLogStreaming warning
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {…}
```

> Logging Error: Failed to initialize logging system. Log messages may be missing. If this issue persists, try setting `IDEPreferLogStreaming=YES` in the active scheme actions environment

At this moment…

- searches for `IDEPreferLogStreaming` on stackoverflow & stackexchange, developer.apple.com, and Xcode help return zero results.
- GitHub search ["IDEPreferLogStreaming  path:*.xcscheme"](https://github.com/search?q=IDEPreferLogStreaming++path%3A*.xcscheme&type=code&ref=advsearch) returns 10 `*.xcscheme` files and 4 issues. However, the github search results are not providing (or pointing to) any significant explanation of what `IDEPreferLogStreaming` actual is doing.

What would be the effect of `IDEPreferLogStreaming=YES` versus `IDEPreferLogStreaming=NO`?

Configuration: Xcode 15.3, swiftlang-5.10.0.13

---

Notes:

1. In addition to "[*.xcscheme](https://github.com/search?q=IDEPreferLogStreaming++path%3A*.xcscheme&type=code&ref=advsearch)" files, there is some use in "[*.xctestplan](https://github.com/search?q=IDEPreferLogStreaming++path%3A*.xctestplan&type=code)", "[*.plist](https://github.com/search?q=IDEPreferLogStreaming++path%3A*.plist&type=code)", and "[*.liquid](https://github.com/search?q=IDEPreferLogStreaming++path%3A*.liquid&type=code)" files as well.

Comment: Just from the name, my guess is that setting it to `YES` would make it "prefer" streaming the logs (perhaps using the `log stream` command), as opposed to whatever Xcode's "logging system", which has "failed to initialise", would have done.

Answer (score 5):

I started getting the same Logging Error message following a recent Xcode update.  I don't know what setting IDEPreferLogStreaming=NO does, but setting it to YES as suggested fixed the problem.  It wasn't clear to me at first where to make the change, here's how:

1. In the top bar of your Xcode window, click on your project name in the status bar
2. Select "Edit Scheme" in the pop-up menu
3. In "Environment Variables", click "+"
4. Type in: IDEPreferLogStreaming=YES
5. Close

Comment: The error says to put it in "Environment Variables." Really put it in "Arguments Passed On Launch"?

Comment: Thank you @samkass, "Environment Variables" works and better matches suggestion, answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have to say to Apple, that the description to fix this issue could have been expressed in a much clearer way. ;)

Comment: In xcode 15.3 it's under Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme (CMD + <)
Then go to "Arguments" tab and add it under "Environment Variables"

Comment: @ndraiman Just for completeness: mrzzmr's way also still works with Xcode 15.3.