# Logging Error: Failed to initialize logging system. Log messages may be missing.?

Tags: swift, xcode

> Logging Error: Failed to initialize logging system. Log messages may be missing. If this issue persists, try setting IDEPreferLogStreaming=YES in the active scheme actions environment variables.

Has anyone else encountered this message?

Where is `IDEPreferLogStreaming` located? I don't know what any of this means.

It's building my app successfully but then loading it like its a computer using floppy discs (crazy slow).

Any ideas?

I tried wiping my OS and reinstalling. I've reinstalled Xcode twice now. Nothing.

A colleague of mine is working on the same SwifUI project with no issues.

Comment: My project started doing the same thing yesterday. I upgraded AdMob and Firebase among other dependent packages... do you use those? Edit: Someone else seems to have asked this yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78117572/what-is-the-definition-and-action-of-xcode-scheme-environment-variable-ideprefer

Comment: It ended up being XCode 15.3. I downgraded to 15.1 and now it works fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To find IDEPreferLogStreaming, you need to go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and then add it as a new Environment Variable yourself. For me it didnt solve the issue though:
[image: Edit Scheme Area]

Edit: it works for me now as well. Probably I was to quick saying it doesnt. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 16):

Set this in Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run->Arguments->Environment Variable

IDELogRedirectionPolicy oslogToStdio

OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disable

Comment: This worked for me but I had to set `IDEPreferLogStreaming` to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when upgrading from Xcode 15.2 to 15.3. What worked for me was to check the all the targets and remove the unnecessary files found in the Test and UITest target's Build Phases -> Compile Resources section. If you already have target dependencies linking to your main target, you should only need to compile the test files (e.g. ...UITests.swift, ...UITestsLaunchTests.swift) that are directly linked to your Test target. I hope this helps!